# Using Pubnub + GCM with two different apps

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I am developing two different apps, and require them to be able to join the same pubnub channels and send GCM push messages to each other. I have read [this question + answer](https://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/563/create-chat-room-between-two-pubnub-app), though aimed at iOS it still applies. The answer given from that link is below:

> No, you can't do that. You are sort of out of luck for now. If you have two different iOS apps then you have two choices.
>
> 1) 1 PubNub key set for both apps and push notifications for only one of them
>
> 2) 2 PubNub key set so each iOS app has a different pub/sub key and each has its own push cert
>
> But with option #2, if you want to have app1 talk to app2, you need to >publish twice: once on app1's keys and once on app2's keys. Not recommended.
>
> The multi-cert feature is key for this sort of use case.

As I understand it the ability to have two different apps both receive push messages is not yet available, so option 1) above is what I am trying to go for here. My main question is *how* to choose which app receives the push messages? Right now app A is receiving push but I want to receive them on app B.

- How to choose which app receives the push notifications?

Comment: Both apps will receive push notifications. One will receive them on on sub-key and the other app on another sub-key. All realtime pub/sub will be on just one of those keys. And depending on the app's requirements, you may not have to publish the push notifications (APNS/GCM) on both keys. I will follow up with more details and a diagram soon. And the good news is that we are close to a multi-cert feature. Maybe a few months out.

Comment: Both apps _can_ receive push notifications by using two different pub and sub keys. I am using and want to deal with only a single sub/pub key and have seen that as of right now it is not possible for both apps to receive push notification, only one. I have tried various ways to "switch" which app gets to be on the push receiving side, but I am finding that the push messages tend to want to be displayed on the other one instead. My question was how I can select which app is on the receiving side of the push messages.

Comment: You can't select which app gets the push notification at runtime. At this time, you need two sub-keys to do this: one for one app and one for the other and you publish to one pub/sub key for realtime messages and you publish to one, the other or both keys to send the push notification to one the other or both. We'll post back with details soon.

Comment: The reason I ask is because app A is sending a regular pubnub message to app B, while app B responds with a PnMessage and a GCM payload. App A does not receive the push. By receive I mean the broadcast receiver does not get called. This means that app B is currently set up to receive pushes even though app A isn't sending any. There doesn't seem to be a way to flip it around. I'm curious to know how Pubnub decides which app will be the designated push receiver, and what I can do to have more control over it.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand something first: are both apps registering for GCM push notifications using the same sub-key and both apps are using the same GCM API Key?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: OK, can you [debug using the the pndebug channel technique](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/mobile-gateway#advanced_troubleshooting_enabling_advanced_debug)? You will want to replace the `pn_apns` to be  `pn_gcm` with a GCM formatted payload, of course. Let me know what you see on the -pndebug channel when you publish a push message. I'm also going to need your sub-key and channel name you used. You might be best to send details to support@pubnub.com and include this SO link so we can track it to resolution and post back here.